# Ups shipping rate variation in magento website and UPS website calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, ups

I have configured the UPS shipping method in magento with correct details.
During checkout, the UPS shipping rates are displayed. 
But when I compared those shipping rates(Which displayed during checkout) with the UPS site(Calculate Time and Cost) Shipping rate. It varies.

It has been configured correctly. But dont know what makes the variation.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have negotiated UPS rates for your website?

Are you logging into the UPS site with the same credentials as your website has configured when getting Time and Cost to increase your chances of seeing those same negotiated rates?

If you're using XML with UPS, have you tried doing a `var_dump($debugData['request'])` in the `try` portion of the curl request in `_getXmlQuotes()` to confirm that you have your shipper number configured correctly and that it's getting passed via:

```
    if ($this->getConfigFlag('negotiated_active')
            && ($shipper = $this->getConfigData('shipper_number')) ) {
        $xmlRequest .= "<ShipperNumber>{$shipper}</ShipperNumber>";
```

I found that sometimes we'd see different rates if I was not obtaining and passing the correct params e.g. `destRegionCode`, `19_destPostal`, `22_destCountry`.  I added a call to the `TimeInTransit` API to make sure we had the matching region code.

Comment: Thanks for response. i will let you know once your solution helps.